# Matplotlib Legend (different result)

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, legend

i'm newbie in matplotlib, but i found a different when i code using python list, and numpy array.

- Python List code

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    names = ['Sunny','Bunny','Chinny','Vinny','Pinny']
    marks = np.array([700,300,600,400,100])
    x = np.arange(len(names)) #[0,1,2,3,4]
    y = x
    scat = plt.scatter(x,y,s=marks,c=x,cmap='prism')
    plt.legend(handles=scat.legend_elements()[0],labels=names)
    plt.show()
```

- numpy array code

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    
    names = np.array(['Sunny','Bunny','Chinny','Vinny','Pinny'])
    marks = np.array([700,300,600,400,100])
    x = np.arange(names.size) #[0,1,2,3,4]
    y = x
    scat = plt.scatter(x,y,s=marks,c=x,cmap='prism')
    plt.legend(handles=scat.legend_elements()[0],labels=names)
    plt.show()
```

Why do I get an error in numpy array code?
This is the error:

```
    Exception has occurred: ValueError
    The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass in names array as a list when you set the legends, like this:

```
plt.legend(handles=scat.legend_elements()[0],labels=list(names))
```

If you look at the error traceback of you original code, it fails here:

```
   1307     # if got both handles and labels as kwargs, make same length
-> 1308     if handles and labels:
   1309         handles, labels = zip(*zip(handles, labels))
   1310 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`if handles and labels` expects the labels argument to be a list and passing a numpy array raises the `ValueError`. It probably should be a `TypeError` instead, if you want you can raise an issue at their repository.

Comment: so can't i use numpy array as an labels keyword argument in plt.legend()? must i use list instead?

or must i cast the numpy array as a list?

Comment: yes, you need to use list of strings

Comment: so if i have numpy array, i have to cast it to be python list?

Comment: yes, `list(your_array)` will work